# Flask-login shows unicode type not callable

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I tried using Flask-Login to handle my login and session.

On registration process, once all details validated, i can use login_user(user) and redirect to homepage.

I have problem doing the Login process.
Upon trying to login, there is an error raised in login_user(user)

```
'unicode' object is not callable'
```

On flask-login documentation it says that get_id() must return a unicode, which I have done.i.e:

```
def get_id(self):
    return text_type(self.id)
```

I have imported text_type (from six import text_type). Previously I just wrote return self.id. It says :

```
long object not callable
```

How to solve this ?

below is my login method:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']
    if email and password:
        error = "Invalid email/password!"
        user = session.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            hPass = hash_str(password)
            if user.password == hPass:
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return render_template('login.html', alert=render_template('alert.html', errormsg=error))
        else:
            return render_template('login.html', alert=render_template('alert.html', errormsg=error))

else:
    return render_template('login.html')
```

It raises error on line **login_user(user)**
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

So basically the error was due to using keyword 'id' inside my load_user

Changed it to:

```
def load_user(userid):
    user_id = int(userid)
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

On my User class:

```
def get_id(self):
    return unicode(self.id)
```